# Intercept function call

Tags: clojure

I have built a "sidecar" to my micro services, to perform common monitoring and logging services.

So, i have the sidecar library that basically works by the "template method" pattern and I have a ring middleware that wrapps the calls to my services through the sidecar and it works... But i would like to remove the dependency on ring.

So, my question:
Is there a way to intercept the calls from ring to my API-functions and wrapp it without adding knowledge to neither ring or my API. Simply put, intercept calls to a random named function and replace it with my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke to do this